# ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError doesn't go away in the test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, runtime-error

I created a model with a column named `errors` and when I ran the test I naturally got an `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError`

so I rolled back the migration and changed the column name to `error_messages` and reran the migration. I don't refer to that column yet in any other part of my code.

Now I can create valid objects from this model in the rails console, but still the test is giving the same error. How do I make this error go away?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to refresh the database structure in the testing environment like this:

```
bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```